# Looking for a c# generics version of my current method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a 2 classes:

- Employee
- EmployeeDetails

I have methods like this for `Employee` class:

```
public static Employee LoadEmployee(int id)
{
    StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();

    string selectQuery = " my query with the parameter 'Id' ";
    dbGenerator _db = dbGenerator.Instance.Database;

    DbCommand selectCommand = _db.GetSqlStringCommand(selectQuery.ToString());
    _db.AddInParameter(selectCommand, "@id", System.Data.DbType.String, Id);

    //EXECUTE THE COMMAND
    using (IDataReader dr = _db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand))
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            result = new Employee();
            Employee.LoadDataReader(result, dr);
        }

        dr.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And I have a method doing the same thing with the `EmployeeDetails` class ... no change at all except the return type.

I am sure there are ways to minimize the lines of code and also using the C# generics it will more readable and generics provide type safety without the overhead of multiple implementations.

I need a method in which I can pass the class object, `selectQuery`, `ParameterId` like this

```
public static <T> LoadData<T>(Object object, string selectQuery, int paramId)
{
    // do stuff 

    // return <T>results;
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Not with your current design, where you use static factory methods. Also, could you remove the code from your examples that's the same in both methods and just replace with comments or a placeholder? It's hard to spot the difference with all the boilerplate.

Comment: Are you looking for generics or inheritance?

Comment: @Jodrell This requires the application of both actually.

Comment: Maybe you should use reflection to fill all properties from `IDataReader` but just a suggestion, you could use an ORM tool like NHibernate, Entity Framework to work with these entities. The code to load and get the entity would be smaller and simple than that.

Comment: i am looking for generics, and i know this can be done using Generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others' suggestions of just using an ORM are great, but if you have a good reason for doing this layer from scratch, you could amend your design to look something like this:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public virtual void InitFromDataReader(DataReader dr) { }
}

public class EmployeeDetails : Employee
{
    public override void InitFromDataReader(DataReader dr) { }
}

public static TEmployee LoadEmployee<TEmployee>(int id) where TEmployee : Employee, new()
{
    using (DataReader dr = new DataReader()) 
    {
        var result = new TEmployee();
        result.InitFromDataReader(dr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The main constraint is that you need to have a no-args constructor on your entity objects, otherwise the `LoadEmployee` methods can't create them correctly. That is, unless you explicitly pass a factory object as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use some sort of ORM (EntityFramework or NHibernate), because then you get the *generic* management for free.

However, something like this might work:

```
public static T LoadEntity<T>(int id, StringBuilder selectQuery) where T : Entity
        {
            dbGenerator _db = dbGenerator.Instance.Database;
            DbCommand selectCommand = _db.GetSqlStringCommand(selectQuery.ToString());
            _db.AddInParameter(selectCommand, "@id", System.Data.DbType.String, Id);
            //EXECUTE THE COMMAND
            using (IDataReader dr = _db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand))
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    T result = default(T);
                    EntityContext.LoadDataReader(result, dr);
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

As you can see this solution requires that you inherit from `Entity` and that `Entity` contains the method `LoadDataReader`.  Also, you must pass in the query.

Disclaimer: Untested code!

Comment: You're using `EntityContext.LoadDataReader` in your code, not `Entity`

Comment: can you explain me this bit of code. EntityContext.LoadDataReader(result, dr)

Comment: @patel.milanb yeah, I'm assuming there that you are doing more or less the same thing in Employee and EmployeeDetails.  Since you are passing in a reference of the result object.  However, you may need to make that call generic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have both `Employee` and `EmployeeDetails`  Inherit from the same interface so they both have the LoadDataReader method.

then

```
public static T Load<T> (int id) 
    where T: IMyInterface
```

You maye need to do some reflection or something fancy in your LoadDataReader method.

Answer (score 1):

First, provide a common ground for both the `EmployeeDataReader` and the `EmployeeDetailsDataReader`.

Generics help here to provide a different return type. So, you'll need a base class (or interface) to handle that. Eg, `EmployeeDataReaderBase<TEmployee>`.

The datareaders can then inherit from this base class.

Then change your method to:

```
public static Employee LoadEmployee<TEmployee>(int id, EmployeeDataReaderBase<TEmployee> datareader)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use "interface inheritance" with `LoadDataReader` as interface method (assuming LoadDataReader is different for Employee and EmployeeDetails). And then pass an instance to static LoadEmployee method; set the return type to void

```
interface IDataReader
{
   void Load(DataReader reader);
}

public class Employee : IDataReader
{
   // some code... members...

   public void Load(DataReader reader)
   {
        /// some code...
   }
}

public static void Load(IDataReader reader, int id)
{
   // lots of code...
   if (dr.Read())
   {        
        // the specific reader would create its own type within... 
        // there by keeping the instance creation with in the LoadDataReader.
        // ex: If reader's type is Employee it would create Employee and setup the object with info from the reader?
        reader.LoadDataReader(dr);

   }
}
```